# Enable perf4j profiled annotation in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, aspectj, perf4j

I'm trying to enable perf4j annotations in IntelliJ but I'm struggling to configure AspectJ correctly. More specifically, the log file is created correctly but lacks any data from the annotated method.

These are the relevant extracts of the configuration:

**logback.xml**

```xml
<configuration debug="true">

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="statistics" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>./target/statisticsLogback.log</file>
    <append>false</append>
    <layout>
        <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="coalescingStatistics" class="org.perf4j.logback.AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <timeSlice>1000</timeSlice>
    <appender-ref ref="statistics"/>
</appender>

<appender name="listAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.read.ListAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <timeSlice>1000</timeSlice>
</appender>

<logger name="org.perf4j.TimingLogger" level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="coalescingStatistics" />
    <appender-ref ref="listAppender"/>
</logger>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

**aop.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aspectj>
    <!--
     We only want to weave in the log4j TimingAspect into the @Profiled classes.
     Note that Perf4J provides TimingAspects for the most popular Java logging
     frameworks and facades: log4j, java.util.logging, Apache Commons Logging
     and SLF4J. The TimingAspect you specify here will depend on which logging
     framework you wish to use in your code.
    -->
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="org.perf4j.slf4j.aop.TimingAspect"/>
        <!-- if SLF4J/logback use org.perf4j.slf4j.aop.TimingAspect instead -->
    </aspects>
    <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
        <!--
         Here is where we specify the classes to be woven. You can specify package
         names like com.company.project.*
        -->
        <include within="com.mycode.myproject.mypackage.*"/>
        <include within="org.perf4j.slf4j.aop.*"/>
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

Finally, the related test method is tagged with the @Profiled annotation, this is part of the package defined in aop.xml.

This configuration results in the log file being produced (which suggests that the logback.xml is configured correctly), however, it only contains headers and no statistics from the tagged method.

The main question I have is where the AspectJ configuration should go within IntelliJ. I have included the aop.xml under a manually created META-INF folder in the src folder but I'm not sure this is detected by AspectJ at all.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I have made some progress on this since my initial post, specifically, introducing two changes:
i) included -javaagent:lib\aspectjweaver.jar
ii) moved aop.xml into the META-INF folder.
The aop configuration is now being picked up as it logs the configuration details and it also mentions the method being profiled.
The issue now is that the thread being profiled crashes, it doesn't log any exceptions but via debug the issue seems to be related to a ClassNotFoundException in org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.Factory when trying to instantiate org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.

To isolate the issue, I have removed all the Maven imports of AspectJ and used the jars provided by the installation package but the issue persists, also the fact that the application crashes without any logging makes the issue tracking harder.

**UPDATE**

To clarify:

- After reading more about this, including the manual in the wayback link (thanks for that), I realized I was mixing up load-time / compile-time approach. Since then I tried both methods as described in the guide but with the same results described in my earlier update.
- As per above, I do start the application with the AspectJ weaver option (-javaagent)
- The build is done via IDE, as per above at the moment I have removed the AspectJ / perf4j dependencies from Maven and linked to local jars
- aop.xml does get picked up, as mentioned in the update, with no errors or warning, just a confirmation of the weaved method.

Comment: Thanks for the configuration, but I am missing the annotated application code. I know AspectJ well, but not Perf4J. From your aop.xml I conclude that you want to use load-time weaving rather than compile-time, correct? Then do you start your JVM correctly with the AspectJ weaver as a Java agent on the command line? And how do you build your application? With Maven, I hope. That would be better than a pure IDE-dependent build. Please answer all my questions and edit your own question with sample code, then I can better help you.

Comment: Update: I was curious and have created a little Perf4J Maven project. It uses compile-time weaving via AspectJ compiler instead of load-time weaving. Both ways are described in the [developer guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20150507044849/http://perf4j.codehaus.org/devguide.html) (only available via WayBack Machine because Codehaus has been closed long ago), but with manual setup, not with Maven. I prefer Maven because it works in any IDE, such as Eclipse, IDEA, probably also Netbeans (never tried). It works nicely and I see no reason why LTW would not also work.

Comment: Another question concerning LTW: Do you see any AspectJ weaver output on the console with `<weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">`? Any sign the file is being picked up at all?

Comment: Thanks for your time on this. I have updated the post with some more information and an update on current status.

Comment: Please answer my questions. Your update does not.

Comment: For info I ended up bypassing the perf4j annotation system with my own which in turn used the perf4j stopwatch & logging features. This way everything works OK and I can still take advantage of the perf4j logging and aggregation features while using an annotation-based tagging. Thanks for the support it helped me to fix several issues along the way.

Comment: You gave up too easily - and I seem to have wasted a lot of time because by now I have prepared a full Maven build with two profiles, one for CTW and one for LTW. Do you always program your own workarounds if you do not understand something? I am quite angry that you asked, but did not answer my follow-up questions by means of which I could have helped you diagnose and solve the problem. Congrats to your "great" entry to StackOverflow. If you go on like this, you will find lots of "friends" here.

Comment: Sorry if mine came across as a lazy approach to this, actually I didn't want to waste your time hence my post. I'd be interested in following up the issue with using perf4j annotations, what put me off was the fact that perf4j requires a closed set of older aspectj jars which made troubleshooting harder and to be frank I felt I was hitting a wall. By the way, I did answer your questions to the best of my understanding in my second update but I apologise if that didn't seem cooperative on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I have added a full Maven example to a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_AJ_Perf4J) which you can just clone and play around with.

Some basic things to consider:

- For compile-time weaving (CTW) you need `aspectjrt.jar` on the classpath when compiling and running the code. You also need to use the AspectJ compiler to build the project, a normal Java compiler is not enough.
- For load-time weaving (LTW) you need `aspectjweaver.jar` as a Java agent on the command line when running the code: `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar`. You also need to add it as a VM argument to your LTW run configuration in IDEA.
- For LTW you also need `META-INF/aop.xml` in your resources folder. Please also note that in order to encompass subpackages you should use the `..*` notation, not just `.*`, e.g. `<include within="de.scrum_master..*"/>`.

You find more information in my project's read-me file.

P.S.: The Perf4J documentation is outdated and the project unmaintained. Thus, it still mentions AspectJ 1.6.x as necessary dependencies. I built and ran everything with the latest AspectJ 1.8.10 and it runs just fine, both from Maven and IDEA.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's way beyond any help I was hoping to find here. I cloned your repo, tested it and then adapted it to my project which now works with native perf4j annotation :-) Also great to see that despite the library is old it still runs with the latest AspectJ version.